# Hiding Boolean fields from navigation in Dynamic Data site

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, filter, navigation, entities

This question relates to ASP.Net 4 and C#

I have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities site which needs to be tidied up before giving to the users. I'm happy with customising individual list/edit/update pages and have a reasonable understanding of how it works.

My table has 2x columns which are boolean fields. In list.aspx above the data table are drop down select boxes for filtering by foreign keys and boolean fields.

How do I keep the FK navigation but hide the boolean fields?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this, and as it's for "internal" use only I'm happy to use it.

```
<asp:QueryableFilterRepeater>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span id="filter_<%# Eval("Displayname") %>"> 
    ... 
        <asp:DynamicFilter ... />
    </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:QueryableFilterRepeater>
```

Then used CSS to hide the dropdown list.

```
#filter_FieldName { display: none; visibility:hidden; }
```

If I find a better way to do it I'll update this answer.